# GTK: set default button for dialog

Tags: c, dialog, gtk

It seems that GtkDialog automatically sets the focus on the left-most button (which is "Cancel" in my case).
I want to change this default focus to another button, but I cannot go the route of "gtk_dialog_set_default_response" because I have packed the buttons manually into the dialogs action area.

Then, while searching the API doc up and down, I realized that GtkDialog is a descendent of GtkWindow, and thus tried "gtk_window_set_default", which at first gave me some sort of "assertion `gtk_widget_get_can_default (default_widget)' failed" warning. To comply, I used "gtk_widget_set_can_default" on the button, and the warning disappeared.. BUT: the focus is still being set on the "Cancel" button.

Is there really no way other than having to use "gtk_dialog_add_action_widget"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use [`gtk_widget_grab_focus`](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/2.24/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-grab-focus) on the widget which you want to have focus on. The widget has to be *focusable*, which is true by default in case of a button. Here is a sample code for your reference:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

/* Uncomment the below macro to see the default focus */
//#define DEFAULT_FOCUS 

int main(void)
{
    gtk_init (NULL, NULL);
#ifdef DIALOG_WITH_BUTTONS
    GtkWidget * dialog = gtk_dialog_new_with_buttons ("Dialog",
                    NULL,
                    GTK_DIALOG_MODAL,
                    GTK_STOCK_CANCEL,
                    GTK_RESPONSE_CANCEL,
                    GTK_STOCK_OK,
                    GTK_RESPONSE_OK,
                    NULL);
#ifndef DEFAULT_FOCUS
    gtk_widget_grab_focus(gtk_dialog_get_widget_for_response(GTK_DIALOG(dialog), GTK_RESPONSE_OK));
#endif

#else
    GtkWidget *dialog = gtk_dialog_new();
    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(dialog), "Dialog");
    GtkWidget *action_area = gtk_dialog_get_action_area(GTK_DIALOG(dialog));
    GtkWidget *ok_button = gtk_button_new_with_label("OK");
    GtkWidget *cancel_button = gtk_button_new_with_label("Cancel");
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(action_area), cancel_button);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(action_area), ok_button);
    gtk_widget_show_all(dialog);
#ifndef DEFAULT_FOCUS
    gtk_widget_grab_focus(ok_button);
#endif

#endif
    g_signal_connect(dialog, "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);
    gtk_dialog_run(GTK_DIALOG(dialog));
    gtk_main();
    return 0;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes! Thank you very much, this was absolutely what I was looking for, although you didn't have to write that big of an example ;) I am still wondering though why my first attempt with gtk_window_set_default didn't work..

Comment: It could be because it appears that the default widget does not receive focus if there is a focus widget. To make `gtk_window_set_default` work, make sure that the widget can default (which you have done) & set the focus of window to `NULL`, then it should work. So in the code above: `gtk_widget_grab_focus(ok_button);` can be replaced by `gtk_window_set_focus(GTK_WINDOW(dialog), NULL);
gtk_widget_set_can_default(ok_button,TRUE);
gtk_window_set_default(GTK_WINDOW(dialog), ok_button);`